# REPLACE in ColdFusion without losing characters

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a string and I want to use `replace()` to remove some characters without losing character value, including spacing.

Here is an example:

```
Extremely Dissatisfied_______________________________________Extremely Satisfied
```

I want to use replace on this string:

```
<cfoutput>
#REPLACE("#attributes.question.questionsub#","_","","ALL")#
</cfoutput>
```

To get something like

```
Extremely Dissatisfied                                       Extremely Satisfied
```

but instead I am getting this:

```
Extremely DissatisfiedExtremely Satisfied
```

Comment: Well, obviously if you replace with an empty string you're going to lose spacing. You need to replace it with another characters, such as a (non-breaking) space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
<cfoutput>
#REPLACE("#attributes.question.questionsub#","_","&nbsp;","ALL")#
</cfoutput>
```